# Error in creating a conda recipe from a Bitbucket package

Tags: python, bash, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I've a package on Bitbucket which contains code files in Python, R, and bash.
I'm using a laptop running Linux CentOS 7.

I'd like to create a [conda package](https://conda.io/docs/) for it. I've started with creating a conda recipe, but I probably made some mistakes. I'm using conda 4.3.18.
I tried to build my conda recipe with the following command, but it generated several errors that I cannot interpret:

```
$ conda build behst_conda_recipe/

BUILD START: behst--0
pulling from https://bitbucket.org/PROJECT_ADDRESS
searching for changes
no changes found
checkout: 'tip'
updating to branch default
108 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
Package: behst--0
source tree in: /home/davide/miniconda3/conda-bld/behst_1495134385344/work
+ source /home/davide/miniconda3/bin/activate /home/davide/miniconda3/conda-bld/behst_1495134385344/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_plac
+ set -o nounset -o pipefail -o errexit
+ set -o xtrace
+ echo 'Running build.sh'
Running build.sh
INFO conda_build.build:bundle_conda(861): Packaging behst--0
number of files: 0
Fixing permissions
Fixing permissions
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/davide/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda_build/utils.py", line 133, in _copy_with_shell_fallback
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/home/davide/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 581, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'cp -a /home/davide/miniconda3/conda-bld/behst_1495134385344/work/LICENSE /home/davide/miniconda3/conda-bld/behst_1495134385344/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_plac/info/LICENSE.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/davide/miniconda3/bin/conda-build", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(conda_build.cli.main_build.main())
  File "/home/davide/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda_build/cli/main_build.py", line 334, in main
    execute(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/davide/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda_build/cli/main_build.py", line 325, in execute
    noverify=args.no_verify)
  File "/home/davide/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda_build/api.py", line 97, in build
    need_source_download=need_source_download, config=config)
  File "/home/davide/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 1518, in build_tree
    config=config)
  File "/home/davide/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 1154, in build
    built_package = bundlers[output_dict.get('type', 'conda')](output_dict, m, config, env)
  File "/home/davide/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 893, in bundle_conda
    create_info_files(metadata, files, config=config, prefix=config.build_prefix)
  File "/home/davide/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 494, in create_info_files
    copy_license(m, config)
  File "/home/davide/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 272, in copy_license
    locking=config.locking)
  File "/home/davide/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda_build/utils.py", line 177, in copy_into
    _copy_with_shell_fallback(src, dst_fn)
  File "/home/davide/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda_build/utils.py", line 136, in _copy_with_shell_fallback
    raise OSError("Failed to copy {} to {}.  Error was: {}".format(src, dst, e))
OSError: Failed to copy /home/davide/miniconda3/conda-bld/behst_1495134385344/work/LICENSE to /home/davide/miniconda3/conda-bld/behst_1495134385344/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_plac/info/LICENSE.txt.  Error was: Command 'cp -a /home/davide/miniconda3/conda-bld/behst_1495134385344/work/LICENSE /home/davide/miniconda3/conda-bld/behst_1495134385344/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_plac/info/LICENSE.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1
Exception ignored in: <bound method BaseFileLock.__del__ of <filelock.UnixFileLock object at 0x7f30df7349e8>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/davide/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/filelock.py", line 305, in __del__
  File "/home/davide/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/filelock.py", line 292, in release
  File "/home/davide/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/filelock.py", line 371, in _release
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'flock'
```

Does anyone know what these mistakes mean?

EDIT: Here's the meta.yaml file:

```
package:

  name: behst

source:

  hg_url: https://bitbucket.org/PROJECT_ADDRESS

about:

  home: https://bitbucket.org/PROJECT_ADDRESS
  license: BSD
  license_file: LICENSE
```

While the build.sh at the moment is just an echo command:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#$ -cwd
#$ -S /bin/bash
#
set -o nounset -o pipefail -o errexit
set -o xtrace

echo "Running build.sh"
```

Comment: You need to attach the recipe and the build.sh script.

Comment: I would run `'cp -a /home/davide/miniconda3/conda-bld/behst_1495134385344/work/LICENSE /home/davide/miniconda3/conda-bld/behst_1495134385344/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_plac/info/LICENSE.txt'` manually and check it output.

Comment: @grundic I tried, the system says `file name too long`

Comment: That's the answer. Do you know where all these names come from? From conda file?

Comment: @grundic I've no idea... that's the weirdest file name I ever saw in my life... conda generated it. What should I do? Thanks

Comment: @ilmarinen I attached the recipe and the build.sh script

Comment: @DavideChicco.it could you please specify conda version as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144601/discussion-between-davidechicco-it-and-grundic).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your home dir encrypted? Here are [related](https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/1372) [issues](https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/1331) on github.
The solution is to use `--croot` argument pointing somewhere outside your home, for e.g. /tmp/_conda_build_.

Comment: I tried `conda build behst_conda_recipe/ --croot ../temp_conda_recipe`, and got this new error: `source tree in: ../temp_conda_recipe/behst_1495144731757/work
/bin/bash: ../temp_conda_recipe/behst_1495144731757/work/conda_build.sh: No such file or directory` Do you know how to solve this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have your Home directory encrypted. The character length when dealing with encrypted folder is reduced from the normal 255 character length.

Hence the only solution, even as per the contributors for conda, is to use `--croot` with a non encrypted location like /tmp/whateverfolder

```
conda config --prepend pkgs_dirs /tmp/temp_conda_recipe
```

and then

```
conda build behst_conda_recipe/ --croot /tmp/temp_conda_recipe
```

Comment: Thanks but it did not work. Here's the log error: `subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'cp -a /tmp/tmp/behst_1495547326227/work/LICENSE /tmp/tmp/behst_1495547326227/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold/info/LICENSE.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1`

Comment: can you let me know if conda is allowing you to do this :
`conda config --prepend pkgs_dirs /path/to/custom/dir/pkgs`

Comment: That's good news. If you have copy pasted the above command, you will need to create the directories at `/path/to/custom/dir/pkgs`  and execute 
`conda build behst_conda_recipe/ --croot /path/to/custom/dir/pkgs`

Comment: I tried, but I got the same error: `subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'cp -a /tmp/tmp/behst_1495634312259/work/LICENSE /tmp/tmp/behst_1495634312259/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold/info/LICENSE.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1`

Comment: I see you have not changed the path.. i am editing the answer.let me know if it is not running stil.

Comment: Thanks. I tried again but it did not work. `subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'cp -a /tmp/tmp/behst_1495724704582/work/LICENSE /tmp/tmp/behst_1495724704582/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold/info/LICENSE.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1`